# Matlab Find-Replace in Matrix Single Liner?

Tags: matlab, indexing, replace

Say I have the following matrix:

```
1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 0
```

I want to convert it to a different format, where I replace each 1 in each row by its column index, so it would become the following:

```
1 0 3 4 0 0
0 0 3 0 5 0
1 2 3 0 0 6
0 2 3 0 0 6
1 2 3 4 5 0
```

I can do it the 'dumb' way:

```
[H, W] = size(a);
for i = 1:H
    for j = 1:W
        if(a(i, j) == 1) 
            a(i, j) = j;
        end
    end
end
```

But there surely must be a way to do it with one line (perhaps using the 'find' function), anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't super general but does what you want. `find` returns indices into the one-dimensional version of the data, so we need to do a little arithmetic to get the two-d versions:

```
a(a == 1) = floor((find(a == 1) - 1) / size(a, 1)) + 1
```

If you wanted to do the row indices instead, you could use

```
a(a == 1) = mod(find(a == 1) - 1, size(a, 1)) + 1
```

If you were doing this with a big matrix, you might want to assign `find(a == 1)` to a temporary variable first:

```
inds = find(a == 1)
a(inds) = floor((inds - 1) / size(a, 1)) + 1
```

(Note that indexing into `a` with either a list of indices or a matrix of booleans works the same.)

You could also just use `find(a)` if you know the original matrix is only 0s and 1s.

Note that this is just doing manually basically what [@tmpearce's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9639455/344821) does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this looks promising but it does not work correctly. The last row is offset by 1

Comment: @Griffin Whoops, one-indexing strikes again! I fixed my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 3):

you have a matrix `a`

```
[r,c]=ind2sub(size(a),find(a));
a(find(a))=c;
```

Edit: this is doable in one line, since that's important to you:

```
[r,a(find(a))]=ind2sub(size(a),find(a));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that's the most computationally efficient way, however I was looking for a oneliner. +1 anyway.

Comment: @griffin I just edited; this works in a single line, I had it in two for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `meshgrid` to do this:

```
[H, W] = size(a);
a = a.*meshgrid(1:H,1:W);
```

Comment: @Griffin: You're welcome. If you have enough RAM to hold two copies of `a`, then the `meshgrid` solution should be faster than `find` (though you may want to run the profiler to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I have use matlab, so I wont be able to give you the code out of my head. But here is the way I would do it:

Create a vector `1:colums`, repeat it once for each row using `repmat` and then multiply this elementwise with the original matrix.

Also since loops are slow in matlab whereas matrix operations are fast, such a one liner will probably be much faster than the code you have right now.